# Tex capacity exceeded [number of strings = 2078043]

Tags: latex

By setting main_memory, pool_size or stack_size in texmfapp.ini solves respective error.

But, I am getting error for "number of strings"..

Is there any parameter which resolves this error?

I can see there is a parameter max_strings in texmfapp.ini but, is already set to higher value.

Please help ..

This error occuring for me while generating PDF greater than 50k pages I don't have MWE for this issue.  (Compiler used: lualatex)

Comment: X-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562243/tex-capacity-exceeded-number-of-strings-2078043

Comment: It's me ..I didn't get any answer there.

Comment: If you post on different sites, the very minimum you should do is to link to each other post to make sure you don't waste the time of the users willing to help you by looking into a problem that might already be solved on another site.

Comment: Can you try to make a [mre] using some random text like from the lipsum package?